# How to store a Reference Object I want to clone from? Use Singleton?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clone

Situation:

- There is a Project Resource that has many Resources A each of them having many Resources B
- When a new Project is created it shall already start with clones of Resources A having clones of Resources B
- There shall be a Reference Project whose Resources A and B (through A) are cloned from
- Cloning is done because in this way new Projects can update their resources A and B without changing the Reference Project and vice versa

Question:

- How to implement this in Rails?

Ideas:

- Implement a singleton class ''ReferenceProject < Project'' which inherits from Project

  - But STI would be overdone for just one Object?
- Introduce a new column "is_reference_project" to Project

  - But how to ensure that there is only one?

Thanks for any input!
duddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now doing it this way:

- Adding a column to Project called "is_reference" (:boolean)
- Validating on model level that there is only one at the same time according to:

  - [Stackoverflow: only one instance of a model in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348811/only-one-instance-of-a-model-in-rails)
- Adding named_scopes for the Project model
- Adding a ReferenceProjects Controller operating on named_scope